# Full text search in gerrit?

Tags: github, full-text-search, gerrit

With github you can search class name and it'll find any usages of it in your repo. Or basically any word and github will find usages of it.

Is there a way to do the same thing at gerrit?

[image]

Maybe there's a plugin or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerrit does not have any support to code search and AFAIK there isn't a plugin with such feature.

We use [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) to accomplish this. It's a very nice tool.